# FFT and streaming operations with OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Here is what I think may be a strange question.

Does anyone know of a fast implementation of 1D FFT in OpenCL which is not paralleled.

This is why I want a version implemented like this.

I have a current task implementing processing which:

1. Takes in 64 values.
2. Preforms an FFT on this data
3. Preforms more analysis on the output of the FFT
4. Generates about 6 values and returns.

This is repeated about 1-4 million times on different values for the input. Each set of inputs are independent of each other.

Since the input is too large for a single operation I was hopping to either split the inputs into groups or some sort of streaming.

Does anyone know of example code which does something similar.

I am in the early stages of learning OpenCL, but this task is a little more advance.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find some examples of FFT in the NVIDIA, AMD and Intel SDK. And take a look to _OpenCL in Action_ and _OpenCL Programming Guide_ books.

Comment: I have looked at most of these and they are all parallelized versions of FFT.  What I want is a non-parallelized version so each set of inputs are not parallelized within it's execution. I should get better utilization, because of the number of different inputs sets, if there is not need for scheduling of threads within a single operation.

Comment: Why can't you just take a C implementation and then just port it to OpenCL?

Comment: This is what I will most likely do, I was just hoping for a version which had been optimized and tested for GPUs.  In fact I have already identified the version I will port if there is not one available.

Answer (score 1):

some libraries (for example cufft) provide a 'batch' mode fft - like performing many shorter fft's in parallel on different data.

for fixed size 64 you can almost unroll a sequential radix-2 or radix-4 fft (see http://cnx.org/content/m12027/latest/), the first two stages contain only sums and differences, and a few complex multiplications in the subsequent stages. If the input data is real-valued (no imaginary part) then further optimizations are possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-parallel version and still have intention to use GPUs why not just launch a single thread from your host program and inside the kernel use loops for butterfly computations and stages.
i once implemented this thing just for fun.